# Blurred scene with javafx

Tags: javafx, scene

I would like to realize how to make the scene of a main stage blured and transparent, if it's possible of corse.. I have already done this with old swing JFrame and now I am so amazed that it is so difficult to do with new javafx(( I have alredy seen some solution of this issue with javafx but all of them just made a screenshot and then made it blurred, like this:

```
 java.awt.image.BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new java.awt.Rectangle(X, Y, W, H));
```

insted I want that the scene doesn't have a permanent background... Is it possible with javafx?

Thanks for advices)))

Whith old swing it was like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktbxJ.png)

Comment: I've seen that link, but there i don't know why, they always do a snapshot of background and put it as a blurred background of a scene, i don't want it, because when you move a window background doesn't change, I don't want an blurred image, insted I want just blurred background))

Comment: So my problem is that I DON'T WANT createScreenCapture AS A BACKGROUND BECAUSE IT'S REMAINS PERMANENT INSTED I WANT JUST A BLURRED TRANSPARENT BACKGROUND.. For example: I have under my application another application when I start my application it makes  ScreenCapture and put it as a background, now, when I minimaze the  application that was under, the background of my app. remains with that capture ((( take a look there: http://prntscr.com/a2obdh